# How to underscore words/phrases in notes and presentations when it comes to articles?

Tags: articles, emphasis

I am not a native English speaker and in my language we don't have articles.

So, I would like to ask whether you underscore (or make bold) (in your personal notes or in public presentations, etc.) or do not underscore articles.

There is no underscore in this editor so I use bold text instead.

Would you do this:

**A pattern** (the left side)
is matched
if **the values** (the right side)
have the same structure
and
if each term in the pattern can be matched to **the corresponding term**
in **the values**.

or

A **pattern** (the left side)
is matched
if the **values** (the right side)
have the same structure
and
if each term in the pattern can be matched to the **corresponding term**
in the **values**.

or something else completely?

I find this topic very confusing and possess no internal compass when it comes to articles  - so I will be thankful for your advice.

Comment: I don't think you should emphasize any of those. But if you do: A *pattern* (the left side) is matched if the *values* (the right side) have the same structure and if each term in the pattern can be matched to the *corresponding term* in the *values*. Also, I agree that you need both *if*s here for clarity.

Comment: Articles are words with meaning just like any other English word - only bold them if you want their meaning to be emphasized. "The **values**..." emphasizes the concept of "values".  Bolding both words: "**the values**" emphasizes both the "values" and also their definiteness (i.e., uniqueness). In this example, you would not use emphasis on the article.

Answer (score 1):

I am a native English speaker and I would not include the articles when emphasising words/expressions – your second example is the format that I would use.

Aside: I would also not include the second "if" as the first one covers it..."this is the case if condition a is met and condition b is met" rather than "this is the case if condition a is met and if condition b is met".

Comment: Fiona's aside is correct. A construction like "A if B and if C" can sometimes be understood as "A if B *or* C".

Comment: The text was written by a native professional and not me.  This is a learning material and the repetition of the same words is not being seen as a bad thing. It's beneficial. Especially when it comes to programming. Clarity over brevity. Explicit over implicit. P.S. This comment is for future google searches and it is not an attack on the persons who wrote their suggestions which are great for literary works or daily life, but in situations like science, math, computer science and alike - this duplication of the same words is great to not loose the thought.

Comment: I stand by my statement of the redundancy of the second "if". I completely agree with "clarity over brevity" and "explicit over implicit", but do not consider the inclusion of the second "if" to meet either of these criteria. Whilst I can't state categorically that it's incorrect (in which case its inclusion is down to the learning material's style guide), I certainly found it harder to parse than if it hadn't been there. FYI, I am also a native professional...I'm an engineer and programmer by education and have 20 years experience as a technical author for mathematical software.